# change the content of div after submitting data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html

i am new to ajax . i want to submit a data with the help of ajax and then get the new data replacing the old one in the same div as of which the old data was .

here is the jquery for sliding tab
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
    // Vertical Sliding Tabs
    $('div#st_vertical').slideTabs({            
        // Options
        contentAnim: 'slideH',
        contentAnimTime: 600,
        contentEasing: 'easeInOutExpo',
        orientation: 'vertical',
        tabsAnimTime: 300                       
    });     

});
```

ajax

```
function addhubs()
{
var group =$('#customhubs').val();
var user=$('#loginuser').val();
$.ajax({
type:"GET",
url: 'mfrnds.php?val='+group+'&& loguser='+user,
success: function(html){ 



}
});
}
```

the div i want to replace data

```
      <div id="st_vertical" class="st_vertical">

    <div class="st_tabs_container">

        <a href="#prev" class="st_prev"></a>
        <a href="#next" class="st_next"></a>
    <div class="st_slide_container">

            <ul class="st_tabs">
                <?php $sql=mysql_query("select * from groups");
           while($ab=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {
           $gpID[]=$ab['group_id'];
           $gp=$ab['group_id'];
           $gpName=$ab['group_name'];
           ?>
                <li><a href="#stv_content_<?php echo $gp;?>" rel="v_tab_<?php echo $gp;?>" class="st_tab "><?php echo $gpName;?></a></li>
                       <?php
              }
              ?>        </ul>                       


        </div> <!-- /.st_slide_container -->

    </div> <!-- /.st_tabs_container -->
```

and the mfrnds.php of the ajax call file contains query to update the new data.

```
    $user=$_GET['loguser'];
    $group=$_GET['val'];
    $sql=mysql_query("insert into groups (group_name) values ('$group')");
```

how can i update the div   in the above . plz help me .m stuck badly luking for solution from 4 days. thanks

Comment: when i click submit button it triggers the function addhubs()
 and the values og group and user gets passed to mfrnds.php . then i want the div to load the new data from the database replacing old one .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in your addhubs function you should only add one & in your url and concatenate everything without spaces in between such as below.

When the ajax call has finished it returns the contents of the page you requested (mfrnds.php) in the html variable. So you can simply select the div you want and enter the html as you can see below. So here we go...:

**Your Page**

```
<html>
<body>
     <script>
          $(document).ready(function() { 
              setupTabs(); 
          }); 

         function setupTabs() {
               // Vertical Sliding Tabs     
               $('div#st_vertical').slideTabs({  
                    // Options         
                    contentAnim: 'slideH',         
                    contentAnimTime: 600,         
                    contentEasing: 'easeInOutExpo',         
                    orientation: 'vertical',         
                    tabsAnimTime: 300                            
               });   
          }

          function addhubs() {
              var group = $('#customhubs').val();
              var user = $('#loginuser').val();

              $.ajax({
                  type:"GET",
                  url: 'mfrnds.php?val=' + group + '&loguser=' + user,
                  success: function(html) { 
                      //Get div and display the data in there
                      $('div.st_slide_container).html(html);

                      //As your slide effect is gone after you updated this HTML, redo your slide effect:
                      setupTabs();

                  }
              });
          }

     </script>

     <!-- Vertical div -->
     <div id="st_vertical" class="st_vertical"> 
          <div class="st_tabs_container">          
               <a href="#prev" class="st_prev"></a>         
               <a href="#next" class="st_next"></a>     
               <div class="st_slide_container"> 

                    <ul class="st_tabs">
                         <?php 
                         $sql = mysql_query("select * from groups");
                         while($ab = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                              $gp = $ab['group_id'];            
                              $gpName = $ab['group_name']; ?>                 
                              <li>
                                   <a href="#stv_content_<?=$gp?>" rel="v_tab_<?=$gp?>" class="st_tab ">
                                        <?php echo $gpName;?>
                                   </a>
                              </li>
                         <?php
                         }  
                         ?>        
                    </ul>

               </div> <!-- /st_slide_container -->
          </div> <!-- /st_tabs_container -->
     </div> <!-- /st_vertical -->
</body>
</html>
```

So in your **mfrnds.php** you should have a PHP script that uses the val and loguser GET variables and updates the database. After the database has been updated you should return the updated HTML like the following:

***mfrnds.php**

```
<?php
       $user = $_GET['loguser'];     
       $group = $_GET['val'];     
       $sql = mysql_query("insert into groups (group_name) values ('$group')");     ?>

              <ul class="st_tabs">
                     <?php 
                     $sql = mysql_query("select * from groups");
                     while($ab = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                          $gp = $ab['group_id'];            
                          $gpName = $ab['group_name']; ?>                 
                          <li>
                               <a href="#stv_content_<?=$gp?>" rel="v_tab_<?=$gp?>" class="st_tab ">
                                    <?php echo $gpName;?>
                               </a>
                          </li>
                     <?php
                     }  
                     ?>        
              </ul>
```

Note though that this code is basically meant as an example, I don't know what you want to do exactly in mfrnds.php etc, but I hope this gives you a good idea!

Comment: i tried waht u said  jules but it stops my jquery slide effect on the tabs which i refreshed the div of . can any other idea could be suggested plz

Comment: nopes it not working frnd . can u plz help me out if i mail u my file ? m really stuck very bad

Comment: You should just redo your "slide effect" because it's lost after the HTML changed. So re-initiate it after you updated the HTML. I edited my answer but I don't know what and where your tabs are at exactly, so I'm sure you can edit that line to make it work.

Comment: k i tried what u said friend but still it didnt worked , m sorry m troubling you a lot but i really m stuck at this from 5 days now . i added the sliding div and the jquery which triggers it . can you plz luk at it now and suggest some answer . thank you

Comment: I edited my answer. Please have a look, make some adaptations and give it a try. Basically what you do is load the page and setup the tabs through `setupTabs()`. If you submit your form (didn't add that HTML code) you go to `addhubs()` where you make the request to `mfrnds.php`. This page inserts a row and makes a new list of items based on the new records. It's returned in the `success` function, where you paste the data into your html. After this you re-initiate the tabs by calling `setupTabs()` again. And it should work.

Comment: I cannot see the files you have hosted on your "localhost", thus on your own computer. You should upload them somewhere. I just noticed you are doing mysql_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch_assoc. Editing my answer and try again.\

Comment: OMG jules my friend thanks a lot for helping me out . it worked like a charm . finally after 5 days i am able to complete this . all because of you thank you. do tell me if any help ever required . i am a very gud designer . ill be glad to help you out .

Comment: you were using <a href="#stv_content_<?=$gp?> and localhost does not support it, i knew this so i used <li><a href="#stv_content_<?php echo $gp;?> . and it worked . thanks a lot my friend .

Comment: Oh sorry for that. I usually use <?= because it is a lot shorter, so I'm used to it. But indeed, not all servers have it enabled. Please tick my answer as correct and vote it up and I'm happy to have helped you! :)

Comment: i ticked it friend . and u gave me a classic idea of deleting the groups at the same time and loading the new content . HA HA . thank you ,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are almost there.

In your mfrnds.php file add a line to grab the updated rows

use:

PSEUDOCODE

"SELECT * FROM groups"

```
for each row in groups
  echo "<div> groups.name groups.category </div"
```

and then in your callback function

```
success: function(html){ 

   $('.st_tabs').html(html);  //replace the html of the sttabs div with the html echoed out from mfrnds.php

}
```

Comment: thank u for helping me out frnd but it is stopping my jqery slide effect on the tabs inside the div which i want to refresh with adding new names to more tabs .can any thing else u could suggest .

Comment: Yeah you need to reinitialize the slider on that div by adding in the call back this line: $('.st_tabs'.).slider();

Comment: nopes it not working frnd . can u plz help me out if i mail u my file ? m really stuck very bad